# Analyzing noisy data

Tags: data-mining, numerical-analysis

I recently launched a rocket with a barometric altimeter that is accurate to roughly 10 ft (calculated via data acquired during flight).  The recorded data is in time increments of 0.05 sec per sample and a graph of altitude vs. time looks pretty much like it should when zoomed out over the entire flight.

The problem is when I try to calculate other values such as velocity or acceleration from the data, the accuracy of the measurements makes the calculated values pretty much worthless.  What techniques can I use to smooth out the data so that I can calculate (or approximate) reasonable values for the velocity and acceleration?  It is important that major events remain in place in time, most notably the 0 for for the first entry and the highest point during flight (2707).

The altitude data follows and is measured in ft above ground level.  The first time would be 0.00 and each sample is 0.05 seconds after the previous sample.  The spike at the beginning of the flight is due to a technical problem that occurred during liftoff and removing the spike is optimal.

I originally tried using linear interpolation, averaging nearby data points, but it took many iterations to smooth the data enough for integration and the flattening of the curve removed the important apogee and ground level events.

All help is greatly appreciated.  Please note this is not the complete data set and I am looking for suggestions on better ways to analyze the data, not for someone to reply with a transformed data set.  It would be nice to use an algorithm on board future rockets which can predict current altitude/velocity/acceleration without knowing the full flight data, though that is not required.

```
00000
00000
00000
00076
00229
00095
00057
00038
00048
00057
00057
00076
00086
00095
00105
00114
00124
00133
00152
00152
00171
00190
00200
00219
00229
00248
00267
00277
00286
00305
00334
00343
00363
00363
00382
00382
00401
00420
00440
00459
00469
00488
00517
00527
00546
00565
00585
00613
00633
00652
00671
00691
00710
00729
00759
00778
00798
00817
00837
00856
00885
00904
00924
00944
00963
00983
01002
01022
01041
01061
01080
01100
01120
01139
01149
01169
01179
01198
01218
01238
01257
01277
01297
01317
01327
01346
01356
01376
01396
01415
01425
01445
01465
01475
01495
01515
01525
01545
01554
01574
01594
01614
01614
01634
01654
01664
01674
01694
01714
01724
01734
01754
01764
01774
01794
01804
01814
01834
01844
01854
01874
01884
01894
01914
01924
01934
01954
01954
01975
01995
01995
02015
02015
02035
02045
02055
02075
02075
02096
02096
02116
02126
02136
02146
02156
02167
02177
02187
02197
02207
02217
02227
02237
02237
02258
02268
02278
02278
02298
02298
02319
02319
02319
02339
02349
02359
02359
02370
02380
02380
02400
02400
01914
02319
02420
02482
02523
02461
02502
02543
02564
02595
02625
02666
02707
02646
02605
02605
02584
02574
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02554
02543
02554
02554
02554
02554
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02533
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02543
02533
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02543
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02523
02513
02513
02502
02502
02492
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02482
02472
02472
02472
02461
02461
02461
02461
02451
02451
02451
02461
02461
02451
02451
02451
02451
02451
02451
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02441
02431
02441
02431
02441
02431
02420
02431
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02420
02410
02420
02410
02410
02410
02410
02400
02400
02410
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02400
02390
02390
02390
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02380
02370
02370
02380
02370
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02359
02349
02349
02349
02349
02349
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
02339
```

Comment: please use the metric system. We don't want you to accidentally crash on the moon when your target was the neighbor cornfield ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my solution, using a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). You will need to tune the parameters (even +- orders of magnitude) if you want to smooth more or less.

```
#!/usr/bin/env octave

% Kalman filter to smooth measures of altitude and estimate
% speed and acceleration. The continuous time model is more or less as follows:
% derivative of altitude := speed
% derivative of speed := acceleration
% acceleration is a Wiener process

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Discretization of the continuous-time linear system
% 
%   d  |x|   | 0 1 0 | |x|
%  --- |v| = | 0 0 1 | |v|   + "noise"
%   dt |a|   | 0 0 0 | |a|
%
%   y = [1 0 0] |x|     + "measurement noise"
%               |v|
%               |a|
%
st = 0.05;    % Sampling time
A = [1  st st^2/2;
     0  1  st    ;
     0  0  1];
C = [1 0 0];

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Fine-tune these parameters! (in particular qa and R)
% The acceleration follows a "random walk". The greater is the variance qa,
% the more "reactive" the system is expected to be, i.e.
% the more the acceleration is expected to vary
% The greater is R, the more noisy is your measurement instrument
% (less "accuracy" of the barometric altimeter);
% if you increase R, you will smooth the estimate more
qx = 1.0;                      % Variance of model noise for position
qv = 1.0;                      % Variance of model noise for speed
qa = 50.0;                     % Variance of model noise for acceleration
Q  = diag([qx, qv, qa]);
R  = 100.0;                    % Variance of measurement noise
                               % (10^2, if 10ft is the standard deviation)

load data.txt  % Put your measures in this file

est_position     = zeros(length(data), 1);
est_speed        = zeros(length(data), 1);
est_acceleration = zeros(length(data), 1);

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Kalman filter
xhat = [0;0;0];     % Initial estimate
P    = zeros(3,3);  % Initial error variance
for i=1:length(data),
   y = data(i);
   xpred = A*xhat;                                    % Prediction
   Ppred = A*P*A' + Q;                                % Prediction error variance
   Lambdainv = 1/(C*Ppred*C' + R);
   xhat  = xpred + Ppred*C'*Lambdainv*(y - C*xpred);  % Update estimation
   P = Ppred - Ppred*C'*Lambdainv*C*Ppred;            % Update estimation error variance
   est_position(i)     = xhat(1);
   est_speed(i)        = xhat(2);
   est_acceleration(i) = xhat(3);
end

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Plot
figure(1);
hold on;
plot(data, 'k');               % Black: real data
plot(est_position, 'b');       % Blue:  estimated position
plot(est_speed, 'g');          % Green: estimated speed
plot(est_acceleration, 'r');   % Red:   estimated acceleration
pause
```

Comment: I've started reading about this and it looks very promising.  I like how this can be adapted to take multiple input sources.

Comment: The code ran fine and plots. Nice job. But I'm not sure the acceleration plot is right - it imitates the velocity too closely, not its derivative.  A flaw in the code, or is this a quirk of Kalman filtering?

Answer (score 3):

You could try running the data through a low-pass filter. This will smooth out high frequency noise. Maybe a simple FIR.

Also, you could pull your major events from the raw data, but use a polynomial fit for velocity and acceleration data.

Comment: I like your comment about the polynomial fit.  Perhaps the flight could be divided in two: before the thrust is finished and after.  After the thrust a parabola would be a natural fit for a polynomial and before that some polynomial with a slightly higher order (3 or 4?).  Extreme values such as the early "229" should become outliers and disappear.

Comment: This answer is right on track. It just needs a specific name to look up... since acceleration and velocity are derivatives respect to time, you should look into Savitzky-Golay.  It's described in Numerical Recipes and online in many places.  Defined as a low-order polynomial fit at each point, it smooths the data and takes a derivative order as a parameter.  This is better numerically than smoothing and then differentiating in separate steps.  S.G. is especially good at preserving peaks, inflection points etc whereas naive attempts at smoothing typically mush out peaks and other fine detail.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried performing a scrolling window average of your values ? Basically you perform a window of, say 10 values (from 0 to 9), and calculate its average. then you scroll the window one point (from 1 to 10) and recalculate. This will smooth the values while keeping the number of points relatively unchanged. Larger windows give smoother data at the price of loosing more high-frequency information.

You can use the median instead of the average if your data happen to present outlier spikes.

You can also try with [Autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation).

Comment: I actually did try this, however, I only tried it over a window size of 3.  Perhaps some bigger window tests would make for better data, +1

Comment: The shape of the window matters.  If you take a plain simple average of n points to the left and n to the right, along with the point at the center, you get some noise in the output because the points at the ends are entering/leaving the range as you move to calculate the next output point.  Is better to calculate a weighted average - less weight given to points the further they are from the central point.  See other answers for good ways to do this.

Comment: @DarenW : that's a very good idea. as you said, this way you reduce the "all-or-nothing" presence of a point...

Answer (score 1):

One way you can approach analyzing you data is to try to match it too some model, generate a function, and then [test its fitness to your data set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-square_test).... This can be rather complicated and is probably unnecessary... but the point is that instead of generating acceleration/velocity data directly from you data you can match it to your model (rather simple for a rocket, some acceleration upwards followed by a slow constant speed descent.)  At least that how i would do it in a physics experiment.

As for generating some sense of velocity and acceleration during flight this should be as simple averaging the velocity from several different results.  Something along the lines of:
EsitimatedV = Vmeasured*(1/n) + (1 - 1/n)*EstimatedV.  Set n based on how quickly you want your velocity to adjust by.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about rockets. I plotted your points and they look lovely.

Based on what I see in that plot let me assume that there is usually a single apogee and that the function that gave rise to your points has no derivative wrt time at that apogee.

Suggestion:

1. Monitor maximum altitude throughout the flight.
2. Continuously watch for the apogee by (say, simply) comparing the most recent few points with the current maximum.
3. Until you reach the maximum, with (0,0) fixed and some arbitrary set of knots calculate a collection of natural splines up to the current altitude. Use the residuals wrt the splines to decide which data to discard. Recalculate the splines.
4. At the maximum retain the most recently calculate splines. Start calculating a new set of splines for the curve beyond the apogee.

Comment: From my understanding of splines is that they are more useful for generating exact replicas of continuous data than they are interpolating missing or noisy data points.  Am I missing something?  To determine apogee, we take every data point for the last 20 samples and compare it to the last 20 samples before each.  Once all samples show a decline in altitude, we say apogee is the highest recorded value during that interval.

Comment: You're right. Sloppy thinking. Apologies. Was trying to express: it appears to me that this is not the jagged set of data one often sees in a time series and you might omit the task of identifying a complicated error structure. From the beginning of a flight keep fitting easy smooth curves until you hit the apogee, discarding outliers--which appear obvious from the plot that I made. (Are they obvious to you though?) Then, after you hit the apogee start fitting a distinct set of easy smooth curves for the rest of the flight, again discarding outliers. 

In this instance, spline="brain f__t"

Answer (score 0):

ARIMA model and look for autocorrelation in the residual is standard procedure. Volatility model another.